# What is a preterm parser?

Tags: lambda-calculus, parsers, type-checking

I am working with HOL-Light parser and keeping seeing references to preterm parser.

What is a preterm parser?

The most informative statement I find is from the [HOL-Light reference](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~jrh13/hol-light/reference.pdf) for the parse_pretype function.

> This is mostly an internal function; pretypes and preterms are used as
>   an intermediate representation for typechecking and overload
>   resolution and are not normally of concern to users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since HOL Light is based on $\lambda$ Calculus and HOL Light is typed and as we know there is untyped $\lambda$ Calculus and typed $\lambda$ Calculus, HOL Light starts by parsing something close to untyped $\lambda$ Calculus, creating pre-terms. Then it applies a typing checking and typing phase, along with resolving overloaded operators resulting is something closer to typed $\lambda$ Calculus. Obviously HOL is much more than typed $\lambda$ Calculus, but the point here is to understand what pre-term means with regards to parsing.

The only reference I have found for this is in

[Lectures on the Curry-Howard Isomorphism](http://www.worldcat.org/oclc/847901063)
Section 1.2 Pre-terms and $\lambda$-terms.

Specifically how this is done in HOL Light is in the parser module:

The pre-terms are created with

```
let ptm = (parse_pteterm << lex << explode) input
```

and the type checking, etc. is done with

```
let term = (term_of_preterm << (retypecheck [])) ptm
```